# Xcode 11 Beta 3, build error "Unknown attribute 'State'", "Use of undeclared type 'View'" etc

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, xcode11, uikitformac

I build an app with the 2nd beta of Xcode 11, using SwiftUI, and everything worked completely fine, but now, with the 3rd beta, the app isn't even build. I get errors like "Use of undeclared type 'View'", "Unknown attribute 'State'" etc. What can I do? Is the problem in my code or is it just a bug?

**The problem is when I'm trying to build the app to run on my Mac (with UIKit for Mac)**

```swift
@State var score = 0
```

The error is "Unknown attribute 'State'"

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    /*...*/
}
```

The error is "Use of undeclared type 'View'"

Comment: Have you imported the `SwiftUI` framework?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon yes, otherwise it won't work on iOS too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the [Xcode 11 Beta 3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_3_release_notes).

> #### Known Issues
>
> - Xcode 11 doesn’t support working with SwiftUI in an iPad app brought to macOS. (41416222, 51201699)

I downloaded the Xcode 11 Beta 3 myself just to confirm the errors you mentioned, and I had the same issues when trying to build a SwiftUI project for Mac.

I would suggest going back to using Xcode Beta 2 if possible. Unfortunately, Apple doesn't provide download links to previous betas, so hopefully you have a Time Machine backup or Beta 2 still installed on your computer. Otherwise, you might be out of luck until the next beta is released.

Answer (score 13):

Got same issue on Xcode 11.2. Found out that the reason was that somewhere in same module I declared `protocol State {}`. This breaks compiler without any reasonable errors.

Comment: In that case you can simply do @SwiftUI.State

Comment: This is exactly what I did too but `struct State`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same "Unknown attribute 'State'" issue in Beta 5. But I was doing "@state" and not "@State". Case matters. It's hard to notice because both ways are shown as purple.

Comment: This was me. Goodness I was so careful with capitalization too

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a Kotlin multi-platform project, check if your shared module has a component named "State".

Comment: Isn't Kotlin specifically for Android?

Comment: @Joel Fortunately no. You can run it on JVM, JS, and Native. Although you may wanna check if JS and Native are "production-ready" enough for your usecase.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while trying to compile a Swift project created with **Xcode 13** on **Xcode 11**. The problem was that the newer version uses the **SDK 12.1** while the older one uses the **SDK 10.15**. To let the project compile on the older Xcode/SDK I just performed these steps:

- remove the `@main` attribute from the swift source code
- add **Cocoa.framework** in the section **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**
- add a file named **main.m** to the project (no bridge header) with this content:

`#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead @main, please replace @UIApplicationMain.
I've attached screenshots.
https://prnt.sc/vimvwn

Comment: This is also true to macOS Apps. If you run into the error in XCode 11 `Unknown attribute 'Main'` then replace `@Main` with `@NSApplicationMain`. Different issue but same solution.